# Check if checkBoxPreference is "true"

Tags: java, checkbox, preferences

I have Preferences with 10 checkBoxPreferences and I need to list how much it checked, eg 6/10 any idea?
I tried something, but absolutely failed.

Comment: Show us what have your tried anyway.

Comment: What are `CheckBoxPreferences`? You need to provide some more context.

Comment: @Crozin  I (and probably you too)don't care what the failed attempt looks like, but it sure would be nice to have a framework to go on, so that I don't have to guess what `Preferences` is and what `checkBoxPreferences` is

Comment: i have Preference xml file with <CheckBoxPreference>

   i tried use a lot of codes, but i am new in Android develop, so that was propably wrong

Comment: get the value and then compare

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about the CheckBoxPreference class in Android, in which case you need to register a SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and implement this method:

```
private static final String CHECKBOX_KEY = "your_checkboxpreference_key";

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
  if(key.equals(CHECKBOX_KEY)) {
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, true)) {
      //Your code here
    }
  }
}
```